# Embed C library in Java library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I have a Java library for Android which I distribute to third party developers, and I want to embed a C library in it. I've added the library to the project via CMake:

```
add_library(wrapper SHARED wrap.c)
target_link_libraries(wrapper CLibraryTarget)
```

To the library's build.gradle I've added:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

...

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                targets "wrapper",
                "CLibraryTarget"
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.0+"
        }
    }
}
```

In the library, I load the C library with:

```
public class Wrapper {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("wrapper");
  }
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to run a unit test to test some of the Java functions which wrap the C functions, and I get the exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper in java.library.path

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1871)
...
```

This works when I'm linking the C library in an App, but doesn't seem to work in a Java library. Why is the library not loaded? What do I need to do to embed the C library in a Java library for distribution? I can't seem to find any documentation specific to this scenario.

Comment: "I have a Java library for Android" -- what Gradle plugin are you using to build this? `java-library` or `com.android.library`? IOW, you trying to create a JAR or an AAR? If the answer is a JAR, that's your problem.

Comment: `com.android.library`

Comment: "I'm trying to run a unit test to test some of the Java functions which wrap the C functions" -- have you tried switching this to an instrumented test? I haven't tried unit tests of JNI. Beyond that, double check to confirm that the AAR has your C library embedded in it.

Comment: The aar does contain the library at `jni/<arch>/libwrapper.so`, but that is only generated with `assembleRelease`. I haven't tried an instrumented test yet

Comment: It's also present in `build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/<arch>/libwrapper.so`.

Comment: "The aar does contain the library" -- then I would focus on testing the library in an Android environment (instrumented test, scrap app, etc.). IOW, confirm whether the problem is strictly with unit tests or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JUnit tests run on the host machine, and on macOS that requires a dylib library, which is not built by default. There are [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325408/392986) which make gradle build this library, although it was still missing from `java.library.path`, and at that point I realised it was a hack too far for me – while not as fast, it will work correctly if an instrumented test is used instead (just move the test from `src/test` to `src/androidTest`).