# Cmake : Building .dylib to test Android JUnit tests

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am working on Android native project using `C++` code built using `CMake`. Currently my app is running fine and native lib(`.so`) is successfully loaded using `System.loadLibrary()`.

But I want to test `JUnit` tests on my mac in `Android Studio`. When running tests on mac, It throws error

```
myapp.dylib not found.
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

# Declares and names the project.

project("myapplication")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
    
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        myapplication

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp
        native2.cpp)



find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)
```

Here is my cpp file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "header.h"
#include<android/log.h>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

To build `.dylib` when running `cmake` from command line, I get other errors like `jni not found` and `liblog(android log library) not found`.

Is there a way that I can build `.dylib` for mac OS in such a way that it can resolve android specific dependencies like jni and log library?

Comment: Without seeing any code, or better, runnable code - this is tricky to debug

Comment: hi. added cmake file and cpp file